# Dont repeat after shown (Random)

Tags: android, random

I have a button when its pressed it shows a random text.
I have another button thats when pressed it will remove the case so it wont be displayed again. How to do that? 
Here is my code :

```
    public class TasksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);

    final Button tasksbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnfortasks);
    Button removeCase = (Button)findViewById(R.id.remove_case); 


    tasksbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Random taskRandom = new Random();
            TextView tasksView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tasks_textView);
            switch (taskRandom.nextInt() %4) {
                case 0:
                    tasksView.setText("one");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tasksView.setText("two");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tasksView.setText("three");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tasksView.setText("four");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried? There's a pretty simple solution. Use a List, and when you use an entry, remove the item from the List.

Comment: Rather than deleting the case you can use flags to indicate that case is visited and if you click the other button change the flag to something else so you won't display it again.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this thing with the flags? Im new at development but I am learning..

Comment: It's not the best way to do it but You can create 4 different flags for your 4 different text. Every time you pressed the button you can check which state you're in and raise that flag. and next time you can check the flag if it's not raised you'll set the text otherwise you pass the state

Comment: Yes but how do I set the flags?

Comment: @ThanosTokmakis what Esat IBIS meant was that you could declare static booleans which you would put into true once you print out a number. But note that if you do it this way, if you wanted to print out up to number "twenty", you would have a wall of 20 lines just declaring booleans. Personally, I think my way is more elegant, while it maybe is a nanosecond or two slower.

Comment: Ok brother @leonz I will try it.. Many many thanks...

Comment: Shuffle the list of options and then iterate through it.  Voila!  No duplicates until the list is exhausted.

Comment: @ThanosTokmakis Np, if you found my solution good, you could mark my answer below.

Comment: This wont help after all.. Can you @pjs tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
public class TasksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static ArrayList<String> list;

    //REST OF YOUR CODE

    switch (taskRandom.nextInt() %4) {
            case 0:
                if (list.contains("one")) {
                    break;
                }
                tasksView.setText("one");
                list.add("one");
                break;

            //CONTINUE FOR THE REST OF CASES
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an android programmer, so I won't attempt the interface stuff.  However, the following should give you an idea of how to do this with `Collections.shuffle()`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class NoRepeats {

   private static String[] labels = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
   private static ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   private static int idx = -1;

   /*
    * Produces no repeats until the labels have been exhausted, then sticks.
    */
   public static void pushSecondButton() {
      /*
       * To change behavior so it generates new blocks of unrepeated
       * labels after exhausting the list, replace the first 'if'
       * with:
       *         idx = (idx + 1) % labels.length;
       */
      if (idx < labels.length - 1) {
         ++idx;
      }
      if (idx == 0) {
         Collections.shuffle(indices);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i) {
         indices.add(i);
      }

      // fake 7 button pushes to change the label...
      for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
         pushSecondButton();
         System.out.println(labels[indices.get(idx)]);
      }
   }

}
```